# Windows phone 8 enrollment process not succeed

Tags: windows-phone-8, mdm, certenroll

I’ve been trying to enroll a Windows Phone 8 developer device but with no success.

I get to the point where I receive a CSR from the device and I should create a valid response, but no further requests are made from the device.
For the certificate enrollment webservice step I use the following response:

**The provisioning XML:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wap-provisioningdoc version="1.1">
  <characteristic type="CertificateStore">
    <characteristic type="Root">
      <characteristic type="System">
        <characteristic type="690116DA4DD2114A83E8A76C31A72ACFEAAC6022">
          <parm name="EncodedCertificate" value="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" />
        </characteristic>
      </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="My">
      <characteristic type="User">
        <characteristic type="83FFFC44D2CF363AA1DC42D5A60397F5CF1948EF">
          <parm name="EncodedCertificate" value="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" />
        </characteristic>
        <characteristic type="PrivateKeyContainer">
          <parm name="KeySpec" value="2" />
          <parm name="ContainerName" value="ConfigMgrEnrollment" />
          <parm name="ProviderType" value="1" />
        </characteristic>
      </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
  </characteristic>
  <characteristic type="APPLICATION">
    <parm name="APPID" value="w7" />
    <parm name="PROVIDER-ID" value="TestMDMServer" />
    <parm name="NAME" value="Microsoft" />
    <parm name="ADDR" value="https://mydomain.com:443/omadm/WindowsPhone.ashx" />
    <parm name="CONNRETRYFREQ" value="6" />
    <parm name="INITIALBACKOFFTIME" value="30000" />
    <parm name="MAXBACKOFFTIME" value="120000" />
    <parm name="BACKCOMPATRETRYDISABLED" />
    <parm name="DEFAULTENCODING" value="application/vnd.syncml.dm+wbxml" />
    <parm name="SSLCLIENTCERTSEARCHCRITERIA" value="Subject=CN%B1C43CD0-1624-5FBB-8E54-34CF17DFD3A1&amp;Stores=MY%5CUser" />
  </characteristic>
  <characteristic type="Registry">
    <characteristic type="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Enrollment">
      <parm name="RenewalPeriod" value="42" datatype="integer" />
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Enrollment\OmaDmRetry">
      <parm name="NumRetries" value="8" datatype="integer" />
      <parm name="RetryInterval" value="15" datatype="integer" />
      <parm name="AuxNumRetries" value="5" datatype="integer" />
      <parm name="AuxRetryInterval" value="3" datatype="integer" />
      <parm name="Aux2NumRetries" value="0" datatype="integer" />
      <parm name="Aux2RetryInterval" value="480" datatype="integer" />
    </characteristic>
  </characteristic>
  <characteristic type="DMClient">
    <characteristic type="Provider">
      <characteristic type="TestMDMServer">
        <parm name="EntDeviceName" value="Administrator_WindowsPhone" datatype="string" />
      </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
  </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

And the final answer with the Base64 encoded XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pki/2009/01/enrollment/RSTRC/wstep</Action>
    <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:81a5419a-496b-474f-a627-5cdd33eed8ab</a:RelatesTo>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2013-06-18T16:20:59.420Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2014-06-20T00:37:59.420Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
      <RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
        <TokenType>http://schemas.microsoft.com/5.0.0.0/ConfigurationManager/Enrollment/DeviceEnrollmentToken</TokenType>
        <RequestedSecurityToken>
          <BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/5.0.0.0/ConfigurationManager/Enrollment/DeviceEnrollmentProvisionDoc" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd#base64binary" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">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</BinarySecurityToken>
        </RequestedSecurityToken>
        <RequestID xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pki/2009/01/enrollment">0</RequestID>
      </RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    </RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

What is wrong? We sent this last file in response but the device does nothing and the enrollment is not successful. Is it mandatory to have a running OMADM server? Thanks